# ajax calling java method with angujarJs and validate login info

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>Javascript Login Form Validation</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script>

      angular.module("app",[])
      .controller("ctrl", MyCtrl)

       function MyCtrl($scope){
          $scope.attempt = 3;

          $scope.ctrlClickHandler = function(){
              alert("Inside controller: value of myval is " +  $scope.attempt--);


            $scope.username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            $scope.password = document.getElementById("password").value;
              h.get("/controller/listEmployee").succsess(function(response){
                $scope.Employees=response;

                if ( $scope.username == $scope.Employees.empName && $scope.password == $scope.Employees.password){
                    alert ("Login successfully");
                    window.location = "index.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
                    return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        $scope.attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
                    alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
                    // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
                    if( $scope.attempt == 0){
                    document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                    return false;
                    }
                    }
            });
          }       
      };

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="main" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <form id="form_id" method="get" name="myform">

    <label>User Name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrlClickHandler()">Login</button>
    </form></div></div></body></html>


Java method: 

public String listEmployee() {


          String SQL = "select * from employee";
          List <Employee> employees = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForList(SQL);
          return employees.toString();
       }
```

could any one please  correct the my  if condition code into the angularjs function **ctrlClickHandler**  so that i can call the others page.

h.get("**/controller/listEmployee**").succsess(function(response){
            **$scope.Employees=response**;

**/controller/listEmployee** its a java method name listEmployee inside the package name **controller**  and listEmployee  return the string **see above** method:

Comment: Wrong spelling of `succsess`, Also, should be `response.data` to fetch list of employees.

Comment: Typo on "success". Did you define the mapping between your URL and your Java class ? Where is the error at this moment ?

Comment: Hi @ Aigloun and @ Sajal . i corrected the spelling  but still i did not get the response result from server.  i only make a entry  as above with ajax request and did not make any entry inside the java classes for URL mapping. any help @ Aigloun ,@Sajal

Comment: Who is **h.get** ? If you want to make an back-end request using angular, you must inject `$http` service, open your browser debugging tool to see what happens with your request.

Comment: i just changed that with $http.. and provided a complete path for my method.. @ drgPP

Comment: angular.js:8560 GET http://localhost:8080/controller/listEmployee 404 (Not Found)   i got this error on browser with this mothod $http.get("/controller/listEmployee").success(function(data){
        alert(data+"...");
        $scope.Employees=data;